# Use ui-router as state manager for server-side rendered page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a page served by the backend with a big wizard form, and I'm trying to define states with ui-router to show/hide the different sections of the wizard.

I'm hooking an abstract state to the url in which the page is served, and then defining child states.

So something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
    url: '/page/url',
    controller: WizardController,
    controllerAs: 'Wizard',
    resolve: {
        steps: function() { return ['one', 'two']; };
    }
});

$stateProvider.state('parent.one', {
    controller: ChildOneController,
    controllerAs: 'ChildOne'
});

$stateProvider.state('parent.two', {
    controller: ChildTwoController,
    controllerAs: 'ChildTwo'
});
```

and server-side rendered template like this:

```
<!-- served under /page/url -->
<my-directive steps="Wizard.steps"></my-directive>
<section ng-if="Wizard.activeState === 'one'"></section>
<section ng-if="Wizard.activeState === 'two'"></section>
```

My hope is that I can just attach a state controller to the page, and avoid ui-views and loading templates from the angular application. I could avoid the use of the router, but since my wizard is step based, I thought it'd be nice to use the router state machine.

Is this even possible? I'm having a hard time finding a similar example. Thanks!

I'm using angular 1.2.24 and ui-router 0.2.11

http://plnkr.co/edit/5Rx16pNVyZvEEUu3dyZy?p=preview

Comment: why you don't go in the way ui-router works..why you want to depend on server url

Comment: the load time for this page is critical, I don't want to wait for the requests of the different templates or deal with the template cache. The SEO for this specific page is also important and rendering it server side gets the job done easier.